# Creating an alias or function, need to be able to pass in a parameter

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal, bash-alias

I want to wrap 3 lines of execution into an alias, but I also need to pass a parameter when I call it in terminal.

Do I need to create a function for this?

I'm new to this, but I know there are functions in bash also.

```
alias blah=some_call_here; some_other_call $1; some_thing_here
```

The `$1` in the above is the value I want to pass in when I call the alias. So to call it I want it to look like:

```
blah "some text"
```

Not that it has to be text that I pass in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases don't do parameters, so yes.

```
blah() { some_call_here ; some_other_call "$1" ; some_thing_here ; }
```

Comment: how could I set a default value if $1 wasn't passed in?

Comment: With one of the other forms of parameter expansion. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html