# Is there a way to add parameters to a command alias?

Tags: linux, bash, script, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating an alias or function, need to be able to pass in a parameter](https://superuser.com/questions/289117/creating-an-alias-or-function-need-to-be-able-to-pass-in-a-parameter)

Is there a way to do the following:

```
cdproject project1
```

where cdproject is defined as:

```
alias cdproject='cd /path/to/$param'
```

...or do I need to make this into a bash script?  If so, how do I do this?

Comment: `bash`'s `alias` doesn't take parameters. You need a function for this.

Comment: @slhck Thanks; I'm trying to build a simple function but keep getting syntax errors when trying this: function mygo() {cd $1;}

Comment: Use spaces: `function mygo() { cd $1; }`. Bash cares about the whitespace here.

Comment: @slhck: Bash indeed cares about whitespace, and will sooner or later bite you if you forget to double-quote the `$1`.

Comment: @grawity Worth mentioning, yes.