# how to create a the following bash script alias for git based deployment

Tags: bash, git

i would like the following

```
deploy dev
```

to be alias to

```
git checkout deploy/dev && git merge master && git push
```

so that `dev` is a parameter. thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an alias or function, need to be able to pass in a parameter](https://superuser.com/questions/289117/creating-an-alias-or-function-need-to-be-able-to-pass-in-a-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ deploy () {
  git checkout deploy/"$1" && git merge master && git push
}
```